# What does Expected specifier-qualifier-list mean in Xcode/Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I keep getting this error: Expected specifier-qualifier-list before '(' token, on these 2 lines:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) (@Implementation window, hvController;

-(void)dealloc ;@property (nonatomic, retain){
```

P.S. removing the ( only makes the problem worse

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all... Can you please reformat so that it looks exactly like your code? Use the code tag ;-)

Comment: Are you sure you're writing Objective-C code?

Comment: The error should be: "This is completely invalid syntax, start over"

Comment: It means it's time [review Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html) (because that's not quite what you're writing) and switch to using Clang as your compiler (because its error messages do not require an oracle).

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of a train wreck, but I see you're new (as we all were once) so I'll try & be a bit more helpful...

Getting more errors doesn't mean your problems are worse. You just couldn't see the new errors because the old one was in the way. So Kill that pesky '('.

The @property is probably better off in your header file, but anyway it should be followed by the type and name of the thing you want to be a property, and you need a @synthesize for it too.

Your code should look more like this (somewhere in your .h file)...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *hvController;
```

and then (somewhere in your .m file)...

```
@Implementation YourClassName
@synthesize window, hvController;
```

and then (later in your .m file)...

```
 - (Void)dealloc {
     [hvController release];
     [window release];
     [super dealloc];
 }
```

..with lots of other stuff in-between.

...but please get a book or some online tutorials and start with something simpler!